# Using JAW-XS Annotations in Tomcat/Axis2

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, jax-ws, apache-axis

I'm working on a java web services and I would like to use JAW-XS annotations (to configure the web service) and deploy it with tomcat 7/Axis2.

But I always get an error, whatever I try.

So here my web Services (it's just a basic web service for the moment) with the annotations :

**Interface**

```
    package wtp;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface ConverterContract {

        @WebMethod float celsiusToFarenheit(float celsius);
        @WebMethod float farenheitToCelsius(float farenheit);

}
```

**Service implementation**

```
   package wtp;

    import javax.jws.WebService;

    @WebService(endpointInterface = "wtp.ConverterContract")
    public class Converter implements ConverterContract {

        public Converter() {

        }

        public float celsiusToFarenheit(float celsius) {
            return (celsius * 9 / 5) + 32;
        }

        public float farenheitToCelsius(float farenheit) {
            return (farenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;


}
}
```

Then for the deployment, I use Tomcat7 and Axis2 and so are the Server and Runtime preferences in Eclipse.

So to use the orignal WSDL (generate by JAX-WS), the paramater useOriginalwsdl is set to true in the service.xml file.
But It doesn't work...

So here is the output when I launch the web service on tomcat :

**Output**

```
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\f_gil\Documents\eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32\eclipse;;.
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:ConverterProj' did not find a matching property.
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 278 ms
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Démarrage du service Catalina
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:55 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
[ERROR] Unable to find config file.  Creating new servlet engine config file: /WEB-INF/server-config.wsdd
[WARN] Web application uses org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet; please update web.xml to use org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet instead
[INFO] Clustering has been disabled
[INFO] Deploying module: addressing-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/addressing-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: jaxws-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/axis2-jaxws-mar-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: metadataExchange-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/mex-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: mtompolicy-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/mtompolicy-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: ping-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/ping-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: script-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/scripting-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying module: soapmonitor-1.6.2 - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/modules/soapmonitor-1.6.2.mar
[INFO] Deploying JAXWS annotated class wtp.Converter as a service - ConverterService
[INFO] Deploying Web service: Converter - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/services/Converter/
[INFO] Deploying Web service: version-1.6.2.aar - file:/C:/Users/f_gil/Documents/Workspace/AirNavLight_WS/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/wtpwebapps/ConverterProj/WEB-INF/services/version-1.6.2.aar
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:57 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
juil. 11, 2013 11:38:57 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1673 ms
```

Then the http page generate by tomcat :

**Available service page :**
[image: Available service page]

And now the response I get with ?wsdl on ConverterService and Converter :

**ConverterService?wsdl**

```
<error>
<description>
Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service
</description>
<reason>
If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set useOriginalwsdl as false in your services.xml
</reason>
javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Error occurred generating WSDL file for Web service implementation class {wtp.Converter} at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:198) at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.initialize(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:390) at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.getWSDL(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:383) at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1394) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.handleWSDLRequest(ListingAgent.java:327) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:183) at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:260) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621) at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305) at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123) at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99) at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953) at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118) at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023) at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589) at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714) at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source) at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:177) ... 24 more 
</error>
```

**Converter?wsdl**

```
<error>
<description>
Unable to generate WSDL 1.1 for this service
</description>
<reason>
If you wish Axis2 to automatically generate the WSDL 1.1, then please set useOriginalwsdl as false in your services.xml
</reason>
</error>
```

And to finish the output when ?WSDL is hit :

**output when ?WSDL is hit**

```
[ERROR] Error occurred generating WSDL file for Web service implementation class {wtp.Converter}
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.ws.spi.WSToolsObjectFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.generateWsdl(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:177)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.initialize(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:390)
    at org.apache.axis2.jaxws.description.builder.JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.getWSDL(JAXWSRIWSDLGenerator.java:383)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.AxisService.printWSDL(AxisService.java:1394)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.handleWSDLRequest(ListingAgent.java:327)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.ListingAgent.processListService(ListingAgent.java:183)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:260)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

So, as you can see, the WSDL was not generate...

So my questions :

1. Why on the available service page, I can see Converter with no operations specified and a ConverterService with the 2 available operations? I hava only one web service : the interface and the implementation (which specify the endpointInterface).
2. Then How to use JAX-WS annotation with axis2? Does the parameters "useOriginalwsdl" and "useGeneratedWSDLinJAXWS" are relevant?

I try to resolve this errors by adding a setenv.bat file (where I set the CLASSPATH variable) in the bin folder of Tomcat, but it doesn't seem to work. (There is no errors when I run startup.bat).

Here the setenv.bat I wrote :

**setenv.bat**

```
set "CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\lib\tools.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\lib\javaws.jar"
```

So does anyone have any idea of how use JAX-WS annotations and Axis2?

Sorry for the length, but I wanted to provide all available documents/information. 
Thanks

Comment: I will test this afternoon, to create the web service only with JAX-WS annotations, generate the WSDL and then deploy a top down web service with axis2.

Comment: I have some trouble to deploy my JAX-Ws web service with tomcat... I think I'll re-read some tutorial about how web services works on Java.

Comment: I deployed manually the web service on axis2 but a problem still persists... It seems that axis2 does not see the XmlElement and XmlEnumValue annotations (JAXB annotations). Anyone got an idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you are bound to developing a SOAP service ? You may save some time and effort taking the [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) Route. There are lots of problems between versions of Axis.

To answer your original question - [this](http://jubyvictor.wordpress.com/2008/09/08/build-contract-first-web-services-using-cxfjaxwsjaxb-spring/#links) is a post I wrote sometime back, and may help you going

Comment: I don't have choice, I need to use SOAP service. It's required by specifications. I will have a look to your work, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem. Seems like when we create a webservice using Axis2, it creates the wsdl. When you are annotating the class with @WebService annotation, JAX-WS does the same thing. I removed the annotation and created webservice for the class using Axis2, wsdl was properly created.